# VB.Net Custom Time Format

Tags: vb.net, datetime, string-formatting

I have a VB program built in Studio 2017. I need to generate the time in a format which can go on to be used in a filename.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

spits out 12:00:00 for example and the : isn't usable in a filename.

I could do with either removing the : so it would be 1200000 (not particularly readable but suitable for my purposes) or 12-00-00.

I have checked [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) and can't see any ToString format that will do the trick.

My code will put a label (say label1) to the current date and time. Another part will use the Label1.Text to grab the string. So any formatting can happen with Label1.

For example, it will be used as follows;

```
oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument
oDoc.saveas2("C:\Test\" & "DocumentTitle" & "-" & label1.text & ".docx"
```

Is there a way to format the Date string to what I want?

Comment: Why can't you use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss")` or `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")` ?  I sometimes use a period to separate hours, minutes, and seconds:  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the **String.Replace**

```
Dim ActualTime as String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
ActualTime = ActualTime.Replace("/","-").Replace(":","-")
oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument oDoc.saveas2("C:\Test\" & "DocumentTitle" & "-" & ActualTime & ".docx"
```

Not the most optimized but clear to understand. Added a one line replace as suggested by Visual Vincent.

Make sure to check his solution as well.

Comment: Much obliged - I just stumbled across that solution as well and was playing with this; Label2.Text = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")
        Dim input As String = Label2.Text
        Dim aString As String = Replace(input, ":", "-")
        Label2.Text = aString

Comment: Why use a label though instead of using directly a variable in your code?

Comment: you're right - I have adopted your code instead of using the label.

Comment: @AdrianBrown no problem make sure to mark it as an answer so the question is closed and make sure to check Visual Vincent's solution also very practical

Comment: Nice answer! You can actually shorten the replace pattern to one line: `ActualTime = ActualTime.Replace("/","-").Replace(":","-")` :)

Comment: @VisualVincent didn't know if could do a double replace. Yours not bad as well!

Comment: Well `Replace()` always returns a string, so you can keep calling it forever if you'd like. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why add the colons in the first place?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")
```